# Strange behavior of javascript date object. Unable to create correct date

Tags: javascript

When I run the code bellow:

```
var d = new Date(1958, 12, 23);
console.log(d.getFullYear()); 
console.log(d.getMonth());
console.log(d.getDate());
```

It returns the wrong year and month. It jumps to 1959.

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Because months are 0 indexed.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Try running:

```
var d = new Date(1958, 11, 23);
console.log(d.toDateString()); // Tue Dec 23 1958
```

Answer (score 3):

For month, you need to set like this:

```
d = new Date(1958, 12 - 1, 23);
```

Because months are [`0` based index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

**Final Code**

```
var d = new Date(1958, 12 - 1, 23);
console.log(d.getFullYear()); 
console.log(d.getMonth() + 1);
console.log(d.getDate());
```

**Console Preview**

[image]